# Importing some variables from another file using importlib

Tags: python, import, python-importlib

I would like to know if it is possible to import some variables from another python file using `importlib.import_module` function (or another similar). I need to use `importlib` because in my project I employ a variable for the name of the file. For instance, if the name of the file was explicitly given - let this be `myfile` - I would use

```
from myfile import a, b
```

to import variables `a` and `b`.
But for the case of `myfile` being a variable for the file name, I was thinking that I could use something like

```
import importlib
a = importlib.import_module(myfile.a)
```

However this seems to only work for the case of `myfile` being a variable for the name of a package and not a variable for the name of a file. If it is the case of the latter and the name of the file is for instance "foo", the error

```
No module named 'foo.a'; 'foo' is not a package
```

happens. Also, I did not find a way to import the additional variable `b` through the `importlib.import_module` function. Is there any `importlib` function that could do this?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using something like

```
imported_function = getattr(import_module(module_name), function_name)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).